# How to get the phone number of the phone in android code?

Tags: android

I tried googling in google but unable to find the answer

Will anyone please let me know, how can i retrieve the current phone number from the android code. I think phone number will be stored in the sim card.

Thanks & Regards,
SSuman185

Comment: this is the link may be useful to u http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-essentials-using-the-contact-picker/

Answer (score 22):

You can try:

```
TelephonyManager phoneManager = (TelephonyManager) 
    getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String phoneNumber = phoneManager.getLine1Number();
```

Needs `READ_PHONE_STATE` permission.

Comment: Hi Sebastian, I am sorry actually it was returning some number i thought it will be the phone number and when i printed i came to know that it is only 2 digit, but actually phone number is 10 digit right. Please help me if u know how to get the 10 digit phone number

Comment: Doesn't work for me either (Android 2.1 and 2.2 with provider Telstra). In my case it always returns empty. Also Android itself in "About Phone" has number as empty.

Comment: There is no reliable method to get the phone number of the device.

Comment: It doesn't work for me,am using android 4.4, Please let me know, Is there any way to find this?

Answer (score 0):

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String phonenumber = tm.getLine1Number();
```

[This](http://code.google.com/p/krvarma-android-samples/source/browse/trunk/PhoneStateSample/src/com/varma/samples/phonestatesample/PhoneStateSample.java) link may be the best collection of TelephonyManager related answers. But still it is not guaranteed that you will be returned a telephone number.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8590115/get-telephone-number-of-device) out!