# Get telephone number of device

Tags: android, phone-number

I am making an app in which I have to get the mobile number of the GSM device and I used the following code to show to phone no in a TextView, but all in vain. Can anyone help me do this.

```
TelephonyManager mTelephonyMgr;
    mTelephonyMgr = (TelephonyManager)
        getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

    String number = mTelephonyMgr.getLine1Number();

    Phoneno=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.Phoneno);


    Phoneno.setText(number);
```

Comment: Any error? , What can you see?

Comment: A.Quiroga, i get nothing means , it displays nothing and i am using gsm device

Comment: what you need exactly???

Comment: Most phones just return null for getLine1Number(). As far as I know, there is no way to get the active phone-number from code.

Comment: Requires permission READ_PHONE_STATE

Comment: I've been searching and it depends on each mobile , some send null some sends the real number. It seems to not have a good way to get it.

Comment: A.Quiroga, It means there is no way to get mobile no

Comment: Dr.nik , i have used that permission but it returned nothing

Comment: It means that i have not seen a way to have the number in all phones . But there must be one . Try searching harder.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. It doesnt even return null.
It just returns an empty string

Comment: did u try logging the `String number` ?,i hope thrs no camouflaging of text issue

Answer (score 2):

make sure you Requires permission **READ_PHONE_STATE** in manifest

Hope [**This**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480288/get-phone-number-in-android-sdk) will help you

Comment: i used the permission mentioned by you but still it is not displaying nothing

Answer (score 0):

[Check this example](http://code.google.com/p/krvarma-android-samples/source/browse/trunk/PhoneStateSample/src/com/varma/samples/phonestatesample/PhoneStateSample.java), it will help you to find out the issue.

Answer (score 0):

TelephonyManager.getLine1Number() is the only solution available till now.Actually sim does not contains info about the number .It is delivered by the network only.Also this is sim dependent .For some device it (TelephonyManager.getLine1Number()) will work.For some it may not.